# meaning of the sentence

Tags: значения

> Такой ответ, покозание человека вникающего детали, то есть, такой человек будут досконально разбираться в рабочих вопросах. **Способность подвергать вещи сомнению осмыслению очень важная черта которая ценит работодателю.**

Is the last sentence in the passage correctly formed ? If yes, what is the object and the verb in that expression - **подвергать вещи сомнению осмыслению** - does the verb **подвергать** relate to the noun **сомнению** or **осмыслению** ?

Comment: a) asking for translation is out of scope on this site. b) text you quote is incredibly badly written. It has grammatical mistakes, misses a lot of commas and is not exactly clear even for a native.

Comment: Does the last sentence also contain such mistakes? I knew what does phrasel verb "подвергать что-то сомнению" means but I can't sort it out in that sentence. I doubt that the verb **подвергать**  is connected with  **сомнению** in the sentence?

Comment: @Alissa  I've reworded it,  please have a look again.

Comment: `does the verb подвергать relate to the noun сомнению or осмыслению ?` It's connected to both at the same time, so it's a mistake (missing a comma and/or a conjunction).

Comment: I considered  - вещи сомнению  as object here, with a slight rewording it will look like this  - **подвергать осмыслению  вещи сомнению** - would it not make any sense after that?

Comment: @CavidHummatov No, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for this trove. I am copying it into grammar Nazi forum :-D

Comment: Способность подвергать вещи сомнению или  осмыслению – очень важная черта, которая ценится  работодателем.@CavidHummatov

Comment: болшое спасибо @V.V